# duplicate editing in eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse, ide

my eclipse ide is weird: it complains some source errors even after I revised, and I have to cut off the whole compilation unit and paste back again. And, when I cut off a source file, I have to cut off twice: ctrl-A, ctrl-X (the content is still there), ctrl-A, ctrl-X, ctrl-V. this problem happens on both of my two linux boxes.

what should I do for fixing it?

**supplement**

eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2.

my box: debian squeeze.

.classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="class" path="source"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="JRE_LIB" sourcepath="JRE_SRC"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="/home/foo/big/build/class"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="/home/foo/big/test/class"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/foo/big/build/jar/big.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/foo/big/library/testng-6.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

.project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>big</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
    <linkedResources>
        <link>
            <name>class</name>
            <type>2</type>
            <location>/home/foo/big/build/class</location>
        </link>
        <link>
            <name>source</name>
            <type>2</type>
            <location>/home/foo/big/source</location>
        </link>
    </linkedResources>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: What version of eclipse and what platform?

Comment: Can you share the .classpath and .project file source.